# Get total seconds hourly given a list of start time and end time

Tags: java

I have a list of start times and end times when the user is active on my app.
I have to calculate the total time in seconds that the user is active on my application and classify them hourly.

For example

```
start time: 28/06/2021 13:14:15, end time: 28/06/2021 15:12:09
start time: 28/06/2021 23:14:15, end time: 29/06/2021 01:12:09
start time: 28/06/2021 8:14:15, end time: 28/06/2021 9:12:09
start time: 28/06/2021 1:14:15, end time: 28/06/2021 1:16:09
```

For the above list, I would like to calculate the amount of time user has been active in total between 00-01, 01-02, 02-03 .... 23-00.

I have written following code:

```
for (Object object: objectList) {

            if (object.getStartTime().equalsIgnoreCase(object.getEndTime())) continue;

            String[] startTimeArray = object.getStartTime().split(" ")[1].split(":");
            String[] endTimeArray = object.getEndTime().split(" ")[1].split(":");

            int startHour = Integer.parseInt(startTimeArray[0]);
            int endHour = Integer.parseInt(endTimeArray[0]);

            if (startHour == endHour) {
                // difference between two dates getTime gives you difference of time in milliseconds.
                // dividing that by 1000 will give you difference in seconds.
                hourlyUsageList[startHour] += (MyUtils.dateFormat.parse(object.getEndTime()).getTime() -
                        MyUtils.dateFormat.parse(object.getStartTime()).getTime()) / 1000;
            } else {

                int startMinute = Integer.parseInt(startTimeArray[1]);
                int endMinute = Integer.parseInt(endTimeArray[1]);
                int startSecond = Integer.parseInt(startTimeArray[2]);
                int endSecond = Integer.parseInt(endTimeArray[2]);

                hourlyUsageList[startHour] += (3600 - (startMinute * 60L) - startSecond);
                hourlyUsageList[endHour] += ((endMinute * 60L) + endSecond);

                if ((startHour + 1) == endHour) continue;

                // All hours in between start and end hour have to be completely added to usage time.
                for (int i = startHour + 1; (i % 24) != endHour; i++) {
                    hourlyUsageList[i] += 3600;
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code is working as well. However, I would like to know if there is some better and clean code solution for the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) from the Java 8 Date and Time APIs instead of messing around with strings and use [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class to calculate the duration between start and end time more easily to generally make your code more readable.

Comment: Yes. I agree. But they do not help in my case. Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: Do you want a result that says something like "0 to 1 o'clock: 0 seconds, 1 to 2 o'clock: 0 seconds, ..., 13 - 14 o'clock: 2745 seconds, ..."? If yes, definitely use `LocalDateTime` in combination with a `Duration` as @Eritrean recommended, maybe even `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you were about to use a `java.time.LocalDateTime`…
And let's say you would provide the hour slots as well as the usage times in form of pairs of `LocalDateTime`s.

You could create a method that calculates the seconds for a given slot like this:

```java
public static long getSlotSeconds(LocalDateTime fromHourDateTime, LocalDateTime toHourDateTime, 
        LocalDateTime usageFromDateTime, LocalDateTime usageToDateTime) {
    // define some date times as temp variables
    LocalDateTime calculateFrom;
    LocalDateTime calculateTo;
    
    /*
     * find out where the calculation has to begin: 
     *      - usage start
     *      - slot start
     *      - skip this slot resp. return usage time of 0 seconds
     */
    
    // if usage time start was before slot start
    if (usageFromDateTime.isBefore(fromHourDateTime)) {
        // begin calculation at the start of the slot.
        calculateFrom = fromHourDateTime;
    // if usage time started after slot end
    } else if (usageFromDateTime.isAfter(toHourDateTime)) {
        // you will directly know that no time was spent in this slot
        return 0;
    // and otherwise, usage start was within this slot, so
    } else {
        // begin calculation at the start of usage
        calculateFrom = usageFromDateTime;
    }
    
    /*
     * find out which end time to use:
     *      - usage end
     *      - slot end
     */
    
    // if the usage ended before this slot did
    if (usageToDateTime.isBefore(toHourDateTime)) {
        // calculate until the end of usage
        calculateTo = usageToDateTime;
    // and if the slot ended before the usage
    } else {
        // calculate until the end of the slot
        calculateTo = toHourDateTime;
    }
    
    // finally calculate the result in seconds and return it
    return Duration.between(calculateFrom, calculateTo).toSeconds();
}
```

A possible usage of this could look as follows

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // a single example usage time
    String fromOne = "28/06/2021 13:14:15";
    String toOne = "28/06/2021 15:12:09";
    // define how to parse the input Strings
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu H:mm:ss");
    // then parse them
    LocalDateTime fromUsageDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(fromOne, parser);
    LocalDateTime toUsageDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(toOne, parser);
    // define the slot to be checked (here only one relevant for the example usage time)
    LocalTime slotFrom = LocalTime.of(13, 0);
    LocalTime slotTo = LocalTime.of(14, 0);
    // then add the dates of the input, they are relevant for the calculation!
    LocalDateTime slotFromDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(fromUsageDateTime.toLocalDate(),
                                                      slotFrom);
    LocalDateTime slotToDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(toUsageDateTime.toLocalDate(),
                                                    slotTo);
    // call the method and pass the arguments
    long usageSecondsInSlot = getSlotSeconds(slotFromDateTime, slotToDateTime,
                                            fromUsageDateTime, toUsageDateTime);
    // print something that shows you the result and the base of calculation
    System.out.println(String.format("User was using the app between %s and %s for %d seconds", 
            slotFromDateTime, slotToDateTime, usageSecondsInSlot));
}
```

The output produced by this example is

```
User was using the app between 2021-06-28T13:00 and 2021-06-28T14:00 for 2745 seconds
```

This is no out-of-the-box solution working exactly as you wish, but in includes all you need for a more readable way that doesn't need to split `String`s or parse `Integer`s.
The example method only handles a single hour slot and a single usage time.
You will have to make it work for `Collection`s of `LocalDateTime`s or even some custom classes, like `HourSlot` and `UsageTime` yourself.

Comment: Very useful suggestions!